# VirtualBox V5.1.24 r1170 not working Windows 7 due to Beyond Trust privman64.dll

Tags: windows, docker, vagrant, virtualbox, windows-7-x64

I was running VB V5.1.24 & Vagrant 1.9.8 on a Windows 7 Professional. I I could not start the VM from vagrant. 
Failed to open a session for the virtual machine Centos.

Console Error

```
Stderr: VBoxManage.exe: error: The virtual machine 'dt-os' has terminated unexpectedly during startup with exit code -1073741819 (0xc0000005).  More details may be available
 in 'C:\Users\Logs\VBoxHardening.log'
VBoxManage.exe: error: Details: code E_FAIL (0x80004005), component MachineWrap, interface IMachine
```

Log File

```
257c.17c0: supR3HardenedMonitor_LdrLoadDll: pName=C:\Windows\system32\privman64.dll (Input=privman64.dll, rcNtResolve=0xc0150008) *pfFlags=0xffffffff pwszSearchPath=0000000000000000:<flags> [calling]
257c.17c0: supR3HardenedScreenImage/NtCreateSection: cache hit (VINF_SUCCESS) on \Device\HarddiskVolume1\Windows\System32\privman64.dll [lacks WinVerifyTrust]
257c.17c0: supR3HardenedDllNotificationCallback: load   000007fefcf30000 LB 0x0002c000 C:\Windows\system32\privman64.dll [fFlags=0x0]
257c.17c0: supR3HardenedScreenImage/LdrLoadDll: cache hit (VINF_SUCCESS) on \Device\HarddiskVolume1\Windows\System32\privman64.dll [lacks WinVerifyTrust]
784.203c: supR3HardNtChildWaitFor[2]: Quitting: ExitCode=0xc0000005 (rcNtWait=0x0, rcNt1=0x0, rcNt2=0x103, rcNt3=0x103, 506 ms, the end);
20d4.1c98: supR3HardNtChildWaitFor[1]: Quitting: ExitCode=0xc0000005 (rcNtWait=0x0, rcNt1=0x0, rcNt2=0x103, rcNt3=0x103, 1137 ms, the end);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I find out the error was caused by privman64.dll[from power broker windows client] certificate is un-trusted by virtual box because the installed version privman64 certificate is valid only 2012-2015.
Unfortunately i could not uninstall power broker software,
So i updated new version which have valid certificate, then issue gone. 
Otherwise downgrade virtual box to V 4.1.12 then issue not occurs.